# Understanding list behaviour

Tags: r, list, dataframe, nested-lists

I feel like I have a good understanding of data.frames and how they work, but certain aspects of lists are confusing me.

Here is some reproducible data to start:

```
 list_a <- structure(list(`one` = structure(list(
     words = c("a", "b","c", "d", "e", "f")), .Names = "words", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-6L)), 
     `two` = structure(list(words = c("a","s","t","z")), .Names = "words", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))),
     .Names = c("one", "two"))
```

This gives us:

```
list_a
$one
  words
1     a
2     b
3     c
4     d
5     e
6     f

$two
  words
1     a
2     s
3     t
4     z
```

Now I want to loop through the list to return some of the results in the data.frames.

```
list <- list()

for(i in list_a){list <- append(list, list_a$i$words)}
```

This produces no results in list. neither does:

```
for(i in list_a){list <- append(list, list_a[[i]]$words)}
Error in list_a[[i]] : invalid subscript type 'list'
```

I thought perhaps the reason my first loop didn't work was that I was using `list_a$i$words` without defining i as the correct names. So I tried:

```
for(i in names(list_a)){list <- append(list, list_a$i$words)}
```

This still gives me a list of length 0.

So I do not understand why the attempts I tried didnt give the results I expected, I do not know why using the subscripts gave me an error and finally I figured out the correct syntax:

`for(i in list_a){list2 <- append(list2, i$words)}`

However I do not know why this works when using the names method did not?

Comment: Do not append to an object in a `for` loop. Lean to pre-allocate (or use looping functions such as `lapply` that do this for you). Anyway, use `i$words` instead of `list_a$i$words`. The loop iterates over the list elements, i.e., `i` contains the list elements and not their indices.

Comment: Thanks, any insight on the question quality as someone downvoted it and I thought from example data to clarity I've ticked all the boxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arguments to the `for` expression in R consists of:

- LHS, an iterator that will take each value of RHS
- `in`, a language keyword
- RHS, a vector, the length of which defines the number of iterations that will occur.

When you set up the first loop, RHS was a length 2 vector of type "list". On the LHS you have `i` which is a one column data frame. You then asked `$` to extract "i" from list_a, which evaluated to `NULL`. In your second loop, RHS was a length 2 vector of type "character". The same thing occurred.

`$` does not evaluate its index. Use `[[` instead and you will get the answer you expect in the second loop.

```
# initialize
list <- list()
# loop
for (i in names(list_a)) {
    list <- append(list, list_a[[i]]$words)
}
list
# [[1]]
# [1] "a"
#
# [[2]]
# [1] "b"
# ...
```

As mentioned by Roland, appending is very expensive in R, as each iteration creates a new copy of the object. Here is one alternative to try:

```
# create a data frame using all of list_a, 
# coerce to character vector
# then coerce to list
as.list(unname(unlist(do.call(what = "rbind", args = list_a))))
```

Note that "data.frame" objects are just "list" objects with the "data.frame" class attribute applied. So you will see the same behaviour when working with data.frames and `$` with unevaluated names as with lists. Try this:

```
# print mtcars data.frame
mtcars
# set class attribute to NULL
class(mtcars) <- NULL
# mtcars is just a list now :-)
mtcars
```

EDIT: `$` and `[[` are operators, which just means that they are functions that can be used in a special way. You can use them like normal functions too, passing their arguments in round brackets.

```
# $ is a function
`$`(list_a, "one")
#   words
# 1     a
# 2     b
# ...
```

The behaviour of these functions is different. `[[` expects an object which it interprets. `$` expects an element name that it tries to find.

```
i <- "one"
# $ is a function, but there is no element "i"
`$`(list_a, i)
# NULL
# [[ is a function, and an element "one" is present
`[[`(list_a, i)
#   words
# 1     a
# 2     b
# ...
```

Comment: Can you explain the `$` vs `[[ ]]` a bit more. Why would `list_a$i$words` evaluate to`NULL` but `i$words` is correct when in both cases we are indeed looking at `list_a`??

Comment: @Olivia, edited reply with additional explanation. Does that make things clearer?